# Program doesn't work with 10 values in array

Tags: c, arrays

Basically, the max size of the array is 10 and the user is allowed to enter up to 10 values. If the user enters -1 or 0, before entering the ten values, then the loop stops and goes to the next loop. My problem is is that it works perfectly UNTIL I enter 10 values. The result will divide by 9 instead of 10 and print that there are 9 values in the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float numbers[10];
    int i;
    int n;
    int count =0;
    for(i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
        scanf("%f", &numbers[i]);
        if(numbers[i] == -1)
            break;
        if(numbers[i] == 0)
            break;
        count++;
    }


    n = count-1;
    float sum = 0;
    float average;

    for(i = 0; i<=n; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + numbers[i]; 
    }
    average = sum/count;

    printf("The average price of the %d products is %.2f.\n", count, average);  
    return 0;

} //this is the fixed solution.
```

Comment: For `i=10` after first loop, you have `count=10` so `n=9` so in the second for loop you have `i<9` which is `9` values from `numbers[0]` to `numbers[8]`

Comment: Rethink the logic. You need to increment `count` only _after_ checking if the input is not a 0 or a -1. So move `count++` _after_ those two conditions. Don't forget to change `n = count - 1` to `n = count` too! Also, you can eliminate `n` or `count` and use only one variable. Plus, you can use `if...else if` instead of `if...if` since both the conditions will never be true.

Comment: just removed that. error on my point.

Comment: moving the second for loop to i<=n fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it is because of this line

```
n = count-1
```

Can you explain why you are subtracting 1? In the case where you input 10 numbers, count will equal 10. After subtracting 1 you will then only iterate thru the first 9 indexes in the array.

If you need to subtract 1 (to account for the user inputting a 0 or -1), then change the condition in the last for loop to be <= instead.

```
for(i = 0; i<=n; i++)
```

Comment: Worked perfect. Wow thank you. Simple mistake on me.

Comment: @TaylorRiley both ways work, this answer and the other answer. You can increase counter after checking that user didn't input `0` or `-1`.  Or you could go for jordanwillis way.

Answer (score 5):

You should not write `n=count-1;`  
 write `n=count;` instead. And move count++ to the end of loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float numbers[10];
    int i;
    int n;
    int count =0;
    for(i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
        scanf("%f", &numbers[i]);

        if(numbers[i] == -1)
            break;
        if(numbers[i] == 0)
            break;
count++;
    }


    n = count;
    float sum = 0;
    float average;

    for(i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + numbers[i]; 
    }
    average = sum/a;

    printf("The average price of the %d products is %.2f.\n", n, average);  
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: When I do that it doesn't print n correctly on the final print. It will say 5 instead of 4 when I only enter 4 values.

Comment: both worked. Ended up going with my n-1 solution. Fixed it on the main question.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things has to be considered in this program.

1 . `n = count-1;`

```
   for(i = 0; i<n; i++) 
 The count variable contains the number of element in the array, while n has been assigned to count - 1 to access from the 0th position , but while iterating the loop condition `i<n` make the loop to run n-1 time (i.e 9 times in this case).
```

So that the sum calculation failed to calculate the last array element.

2. `average = sum/a;`

   The variable average and sum are float , whereas n is an int, so the type conversion has to be made while calculating the average.

`average = sum/(float)a;`

```
 NOTE : a should be replaced by count , which hold the exact count of the element in array.
```

The complete corrected code is,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float numbers[10];
    int i;
    int n;
    int count =0;
    for(i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
        scanf("%f", &numbers[i]);
        count++;
        if(numbers[i] == -1)
            break;
        if(numbers[i] == 0)
            break;
    }


    n = count-1;
    float sum = 0;
    float average;

    for(i = 0; i<=n; i++)
    {

        sum = sum + numbers[i]; 

    }
    average = sum/(float)count;

    printf("The average price of the %d  products is %.2f.\n", count,  average);  
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Yep just fixed it on my answer. Thank you so much. Ended up working perfectly. A bit tired currently and this program was getting to me lol. Thank you.